# How can qsub command avoid using specific machine

Tags: linux, shell, queue, server

I am using qsub command to submit job to the queue on a server.

As there are some of the nodes that are significantly slower than others, I would like to avoid them.

Is there a flag or a parameter that can avoid my jobs running on those slower computing nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
qsub -q <queuename>
```

or

```
qsub -l nodes=<nodename>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what these commands do? (i.e. how to specify the node names, etc.)